# Rails: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I user friendly_id for all the items. I am getting an error in the cart.rb model saying .. `Couldn't find Product with 'id'=the-pen`

I'm unsure what to do. Any help would be appreciated

**cart.rb**

```
class CartItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_reader :product_id, :quantity

    def initialize product_id, quantity = 1
        @product_id = product_id
        @quantity = quantity
    end

    def increment
        @quantity = @quantity + 1
    end

    def product
        Product.find product_id
    end

    def total_price
        product.price * quantity    
    end


end
```

**ApplicationController.rb**

```
def initialize_cart
    @cart = Cart.build_from_hash session
end
```

**OrderForm.rb**

```
def build_order_items
    @cart.items.each do |item|
        @order.order_items.create! product_id: item.product_id, quantity: item.quantity
    end
```

Comment: What is `Cart.build_from_hash session` do here? What is `Cart` implementation? On which line you're getting the error you've mentioned?

Comment: Its from the  OrderForm model, i'll add to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CartItem's `product` method still uses the `.find` method by itself, which may be throwing the error as you're inputting a string as an argument instead of the numeric ID. Try modifying it to use `.friendly.find` instead.

Hope this helps!